# Find a basis. For a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Find a basis for the subspace of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$ that are divisible by $x^2+1$:
$$k[x]=\{f(x) \in k[x]\ |\ (x^2+1)|f(x), \deg(f(x)) \leq n\}$$

All I did is $f(x)=(x^2+1)*g(x)$ for some g(x) with $\operatorname{deg}(g(x)) \le n-2$. Also, I know $f(x)$ has to be degree $\ge 2$ but the basis I take if take a random polynomial is the standard basis of my whole space of all polynomials degree $n$.

What i found is ${x^2+1,x^3+x,..,X^n+x^n-2}$

Comment: Do you know the basis for all polynomials up to degree $n$?

Comment: I edited your question to make it a little more readable but I don't know what the "and also $(x^2+1) \mid f(x)$" part is supposed to mean.

Comment: ye 1,x,x^2,x^3,..

Comment: $x^2+1$ divides the polynomial

Comment: Oh hold up.  I get it.  It's the subspace where $x^2 +1$ is a factor of the polynomials.

Comment: Hint: how could you change the standard basis to make it into a basis for this space.

Comment: How about this set:  $\{(x^2+1), (x^2+1)x, (x^2+1)x^2, \dots, (x^2+1)x^{n-2}\}$.  It's easy to show that these are linearly independent and there's the right number of them, so... basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that the family $B=(x^k(x^2+1))_{0\le k\le n-2}$ is linearly independent of elements of the given linear space.

Moreover, if $P$ is a polynomial of the given linear space then we have

$$P=(x^2+1)Q$$
where $Q$ has at most the degree $n-2$ so $Q$ is linear combination of $(x^k)_{0\le k\le n-2}$ and the $P$ is a linear combination of $B$. Conclude.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1.If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ say and $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ say then there exists unique polynomials $q(x),r(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $r(x)=0$ or degree of $r(x)\leq $ degree of $g(x)$.

2. If $F[x]$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ then a basis of $F[x]$ is $\{1,x,x^2,....x^n\}$